# PHP Multiple loops to read multiple tables and display in single select element HTML?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I need to display all the values from two table in my HTML input. It has info about a user called recruit who has info from two multiple tables. But only interview_id and course_id I need to display all values in the select menu. The problem is I am just getting last value of each loop. So it displays only one value in `echo $interviewrow[date_time];`  and `echo $courserow[name];` 
Sorry if the formatting is wrong.

Here is my php read values from database which is just before the select element:

```
<?php
$interviewlist = $dbcon->exec("select idinterview, date_time from interview");
for($i=0;$i<$interviewlist;$i++){
    $interviewrow=$dbcon->data_seek($i);
    ?> 

    <?php 
    $recruit= $dbcon->exec("select * from recruit where user_id=".quote_smart($userid));
    if($recruit>0){
        $recruitrow=$dbcon->data_seek($i);   
    }
    $recruitcourse= $dbcon->exec("select idcourse, name from course where idcourse=".quote_smart($recruitrow[course_id])); 
    if($recruitcourse>0)
        $recruitcourserow=$dbcon->data_seek($i); 

    $courselist= $dbcon->exec("select * from course");

    for($i=0;$i<$courselist;$i++){
        $courserow=$dbcon->data_seek($i);

        ?>
```

Here is my html in javascript which appears if select type is recruit which is just after the php read.

```
else if( $(this).val() == 'Recruit' || $(this).val() == 'Recruit-Edit'){
         $('.new-field').remove();

      $('.new-input').append(' <div class="new-field"> <input type="hidden" name="idinterview" value="<?php echo $interviewrow[idinterview];>"><div class="form-group" id="opt"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Date</label><div class="col-sm-10"><select class="form-control" id="date" name="date"><option selected disable>Choose Date</option><option><?php echo $interviewrow[date_time]; ?></option></select></div></div> <?php } ?><div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Applied For</label><div class="col-sm-10"><input name="applied" type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $recruitrow[applied_for]; ?>"></div></div> <div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label">CV</label><div class="col-sm-10"><input accept="application/pdf" class="enable-attache" data-geometry="150x150#" data-value="[<?php echo htmlentities($recruitrow[file]); ?>]" data-uploadurl="<?php echo ATTACHE_DOMAIN; ?>/upload" data-downloadurl="<?php echo ATTACHE_DOMAIN; ?>/view" data-uuid="<?php echo $uuid; ?>" data-expiration="<?php echo $expiration; ?>" data-hmac="<?php echo hash_hmac('sha1', $uuid.$expiration, ATTACHE_SECRET); ?>" type="file" name="cv" id="cv" /></div></div><div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Phone</label><div class="col-sm-10"><input name="phone" type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $recruitrow[phone]; ?>"></div></div> <div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Date Applied</label><div class="col-sm-10"><input name="datea" type="date" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $recruitrow[date_applied]; ?>"></div></div> <input type="hidden" name="idcourse" value="<?php echo $courserow[idcourse];?>"><div class="form-group" id="opt"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Course Enrolled (if any)</label><div class="col-sm-10"><select class="form-control" id="course" name="course"><option selected disable><?php echo $recruitcourserow[name]; ?></option><option><?php echo $courserow[name]; ?></option></select></div></div><?php } ?></div>');
```

Comment: You need to create separate `mysqli_stmt` objects for each query, not reuse the same one. Better yet, combine all the queries into a single query using `JOIN`.

Comment: And why are you using the same `$i` to seek into each query? What makes you think the corresponding rows will be in the same order in all the result sets?

Comment: What database API is this? I thought it was `mysqli`, but it doesn't have an `exec()` method.

Comment: You also shouldn't use the same variable `$i` in nested `for` loops. The inner loop is overwriting the variable used by the outer loop.

Comment: you can use joins to get all the data in one query

Comment: @Barmar exec is a custom written function which has the mysqli stuff

Comment: It's still unclear what's going on with all those `$dbcon->data_seek($i)` calls.   Why do you want the same row number in each query? There's no `ORDER BY`, so how do you know what will be in row `$i`?